# Accessing a Program Over a Network

Tags: networking, active-directory, windows-server-2016

My boss is looking for us to have as little local installs as possible. We're running Active Directory on Server 2016. We're trying to install Platypus Billing System and a Watchguard VPN over a network for users to access from a Mapped Drive.

So far I've read no, but I haven't found many articles/forums on this issue.

So, is there a way to access programs installed on a network share from all the computers on the domain? Or do I have to RDP into a VM to do it?

Comment: Please do not post duplicate questions.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't figure out why my first one is still on hold.  I've edited it to be specific as possible.  I really need this question answered.

Comment: Talk to your software vendor to see if they support this configuration.